# Azure Resource Group Error: A parameter cannot be found that matches parameter name 'EnvironmentName'

Tags: visual-studio, powershell, azure, automated-deploy

I am trying to create an Azure Resource Group project using Visual Studio 2015 by following [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-resource-manager/vs-azure-tools-resource-groups-deployment-projects-create-deploy) tutorial. But when I deploy, it turns out a weird error:

```
[ERROR] Add-AzureRmAccount : A parameter cannot be found that matches parameter name 
[ERROR] 'EnvironmentName'.
[ERROR] At line:1 char:2379
[ERROR] + ... xmg' -AccountId 'myemail@outlook.com' -EnvironmentName 'AzureC ...
[ERROR] +                                                  ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
[ERROR]     + CategoryInfo          : InvalidArgument: (:) [Add-AzureRmAccount], Param 
[ERROR]    eterBindingException
[ERROR]     + FullyQualifiedErrorId : NamedParameterNotFound,Microsoft.Azure.Commands. 
[ERROR]    Profile.AddAzureRMAccountCommand
[ERROR]  
[ERROR] Run Login-AzureRmAccount to login.
```

I updated the latest version of Azure SDK but still the same error. Please help me to resolve this issue.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There was a breaking change in the 4.x release of the Azure PowerShell cmdlets, the short term fix is to roll back to 3.8.

If you used "Install-Module AzureRM" to install the cmdlets, then uninstall and re-install with the -RequiredVersion parameter, e.g.

```
Install-Module AzureRM -RequiredVersion 3.8.0 -Force -AllowClobber
```

If you installed the cmdlets via WebPI/MSI/AzureSDK install, then uninstall Azure PowerShell from control panel and install the 3.8 version from here: https://github.com/Azure/azure-powershell/releases/download/v3.8.0-April2017/azure-powershell.3.8.0.msi

We're working on a fix for 4.x...

Comment: A fix has been deployed to the 4.0.2 version of the cmdlets - you should no longer need to install the older 3.8 version - just make sure you have 4.0.2 and not 4.0 or 4.0.1.